# Best practice to connect DAL to UI layer

Tags: c#, nhibernate, devexpress, iqueryable, 3-tier

I've always been told that designing your application using 3 tiers model is the best practice to separate the data layer and the business logic layer from the presentation.

But when I come to use modern user interface components (like DevExpress), I will lose a lot of great features such as dynamic filtering, paging, dynamic loading ..etc.

and you should implement your own methods that allow the user controls to keep those features.

I read those articles from Ayende the Nhibernate guy:

http://ayende.com/blog/3958/the-dal-should-go-all-the-way-to-ui
http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton
http://ayende.com/blog/4567/the-false-myth-of-encapsulating-data-access-in-the-dal

And now I got confused ! does that mean that I can reference Nhibernate in my UI? for example, can I have code such as:

```
GridView.DataSource = session.Query<Order>();
```

Comment: It's not as easy as you might want it to be in your example, you might end up having serious N+1 SELECT problems, so keep that in mind and tread carefully. But generally NHibernate *is* your data access layer by definition...

Comment: In version 12.2 BindToCustomData was introduced. It's a bit tricksy but it can be used to have a clean layered structure in your webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the problem just from the perspective of the filtering, paging, dynamic loading etc methods and approaches is not the full way to looking to the problem at least for two reasons, the first is because your DAL and DAL interface must provide the suitable API for these mechanisms otherwise your DAL will be considered as an INCOMPLETE DAL, the second which is more important is the ENVIRONMENT of your application/system and here we have a lot of questions which we have to ask to ourselves, or we can name it a strategical decision
1- shall we need to change the database engine with the passage of time?
2- What is the level of complexity of our application/system here I mean the BLL complexity if the majority of our application/system are just CRUD methods we have to ask ourselves do we really need to create BLL

Actually There are a lot of questions here, the answering to these question may drive us to the plain object oriented architecture which is guid us to an object which contains Properties for modeling the data of the object, and (Create, Update, and Delete) instance methods to manipulate the object, and (ReadByID, ReadAll, ReadPage ets) static methods to retrieve the persisted data from the database